# WebView.Invoke(string scriptname, string[]) explanation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

```
WebView1.InvokeScript("eval", args);
```

I want to know whats the meaning of the word "eval". In MSDN library it says its the name of the script. But when I type something else instead of "eval" the code does not work. So whats the meaning of eval ? and what are the other words I can use instead of eval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the name of a (most commonly JavaScript) function within your HTML code. [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is just a predefined JavaScript function.

But this can be anything:

```
// HTML code
<html>
<script>
function alertme(name) {
    alert('My name is: ' + name);
}
</script>
</html>

// C# code
public void Test() {
    WebView1.InvokeScript("alertme", "Inigo Montoya");
}
```

This will show you a pop-up on your webpage printing the string "My name is Inigo Montoya".

Comment: Nice solution. Hey, can you help me with this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708957/c-sharp-metro-xaml-designing-the-page-for-any-of-the-screen